# Java 7 applet plugin URLConnection not getting cookies from browser

Tags: http, cookies, applet, java

Our applet opens an HTTP connection to a server in the same domain with URLConnection. Under JRE 1.6.0_16 plugin the requests automatically got the session management cookies from the browser from the page in which the applet was embedded. Under JRE 1.7.0_01 this doesn't happen; no such cookies are set. The server is unchanged.

If we set a (very insecure) allow-all java.policy on the client workstation then it works as expected in JRE 7. Obviously we can't use this on a public website.

How do we persuade the browser and applet to share the cookies on the outbound connection?

Comment: What Java 6 version: be specific. You might want to check what Java 6 update 29 as well does, because it might be the result of a security change in Java 7 Update 1 and Java 6 Update 29

Comment: Good point. It's Java 1.6.0_16 and 1.7.0_01. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Have you considered using a signed applet?